# Xamarin - error message displayed in wrong position in RecyclerView

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-recyclerview

I have `validate` method inside my RecyclerView Adapter , this method made to validate row before add new row to my adapter , the issue I face when I edit in last row validation error appear in wrong position , I trace my adapter and I am sure it give right position

here is image for reference

[image]

my code I check if focused item is last item and validation is passed to add new row

```
 private void CheckNewItemAddMethod(int position)
        {
            if (Validate(position) && position == ItemCount - 1)
            { 
                    transactionItemModelList.Add(new TransactionItemModel() { ItemID = -1 });
                    NotifyItemInserted(transactionItemModelList.Count - 1);               
            }
        }

 private bool Validate(int pos)
        {
            ItemCustomViewHolder Passedholder = FindViewHolderByPoistion(pos);
            bool valid = true;
            int x = 0;
            if (! int.TryParse(Passedholder.itemCount.Text, out x) || x == 0){
                valid = false;
            }
            int intItemPrice = 0;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Passedholder.itemName.Text) || !int.TryParse(Passedholder.itemPrice.Text, out intItemPrice) || intItemPrice == 0)
            {
                valid = false;
                Passedholder.itemName.SetError(mContext.GetString(Resource.String.empty_field), null);
            }else
            {
                Passedholder.itemName.SetError((string)null, null);
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Passedholder.itemPrice.Text))
            {
                valid = false;
                Passedholder.itemPrice.SetError(mContext.GetString(Resource.String.empty_field), null);
            }
            else
            {
                Passedholder.itemPrice.SetError((string)null, null);
            }
            return valid;
        }
```

**Note** when I scroll it back to right view

any one can guide me why that happen

Comment: "please fill empty field" is not the right position?  Can you provide code when checking `Validate` return value is `true`?

Comment: I update my answer please check